# Setting file mode with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to set the file mode with puppet but it is not being set.

```
file { 'create script':
    ensure  => file,
    path    => "${test_script}/test_script.sh",
    content => template('test/test_script.sh.erb'),
    require => File[$test_script],
    mode    => '0775'
}
```

It creates the file correctly but the mode remains the default 0644.

Comment: Which version of Puppet?  What kind of machine is the target node?

Comment: How is `File[$test_script]` declared?  More generally, please provide a [mcve], including log output from the agent showing the target file being synced.  Puppet has long set file modes just fine, but I can think of a couple of scenarios off the top of my head that could produce the result you report.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was causing the issue. The file was being copied over to another system and required

```
source_permissions => true
```

to keep the permissions and not use puppets.